# Charts.js polar area chart ignores min and max ticks (in primeNG angular wrapper)

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am using primeng angular wrapper of Chart.js

See the code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cpgcnn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbulls-eye-chart%2Fbulls-eye-chart.component.ts

I want to see circles from 0 to 100 radius so I specify

```
        ticks:{
          min:0,
          max:100,
        }
```

But it gets ignored and the max is determined based on the data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the min and max are located at the level of r at least in this version of Chart.js (4.3.3)

```
  scales: {
    r: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cpgcnn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbulls-eye-chart%2Fbulls-eye-chart.component.ts